# shared pointer double deleting

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have an object that is apparently double deleted despite being kept track of by smart pointers. I am new to using smart pointers so I made a simple function to test whether I am using the object correctly.

```
int *a = new int(2);

std::shared_ptr<int> b(a);
std::shared_ptr<int> c(a);
```

This set of lines in the main function causes a runtime error as the pointers go out of scope, why? Aren't smart pointers supposed to be able to handle the deletion of a by themselves?

Comment: Are you deleting a on your own ? you're not supposed to do that. Use make_shared instead of manually allocating a.

Answer (score 10):

A `shared_ptr` expects to *own* the pointed-at object.

What you've done is to create *two* separate smart pointers, each of which thinks it has exclusive ownership of the underlying `int`. They don't know about each other's existence, they don't talk to each other. Therefore, when they go out of scope, both pointers delete the underlying resource, with the obvious result.

When you create a `shared_ptr`, it creates a sort of "management object" which is responsible for the resource's lifetime. When you *copy* a `shared_ptr`, both copies reference the same management object. The management object keeps track of how many `shared_ptr` instances are pointing at this resource. An `int*` by itself has no such "management object", so copying it does not keep track of references.

Here's a minimal rewrite of your code:

```
// incidentally, "make_shared" is the best way to do this, but I'll leave your
// original code intact for now.
int *a = new int(2);

std::shared_ptr<int> b(a);
std::shared_ptr<int> c = b;
```

Now, they both reference the same underlying management object. As each `shared_ptr` is destroyed, the number of references on the `int*` is reduced and when the last reference goes ther object is deleted.

Comment: A better style is to do std::shared_ptr<int> b(new int(2)) to avoid having a transitional pointer a. Having a implies the danger of a) a being deleted by some random code in the scope; b) memory leak when exception occurs before a reaches shared_ptr. The shared_ptr is designed to be able to take raw pointer from and ONLY from the constructor, and that's the reason for it. An even better way is, std::shared_ptr<int> b(std::make_shared<int>) - make_shared has only 1 memory allocation while the previous way has at least two memory allocations.

Comment: @h9uest your point would be a lot more relevant if this wasn't a minimal modification to the code supplied in the original question. It wasn't ever intended to be a perfect example of C++, and never claimed to be. If you read the comment in the code block, you'd see that `make_shared` was mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You are only allowd to make a smartpointer once from a raw pointer. All other shared pointers have to be copies of the first one in order for them to work correctly. Even better: use make shared:

```
 std::shared_ptr<int> sp1 = std::make_shared<int>(2);
 std::shared_ptr<int> sp2 = sp1;
```

EDIT: forgot to add the second pointer

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> b = std::make_shared<int>(2);
std::shared_ptr<int> c = b;
```